# List of all tags in Google Landmark API

Tags: api, tags, identification, google-cloud-vision

I want to use [Google's Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-landmarks#detecting_landmarks_in_a_local_image) for my Android Application. My application needs to know the list of all tags present in this API (all landmark tags out of which response tags will come) Can anybody please help me out. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is not possible to obtain all landmark tags of Google Cloud Vision API.

Bye.